# Calculating differences in average monthly between years

Tags: sql, postgresql, date, window-functions

I have a table which contains average monthly values from a sensor over the last 3 years

Is there a way in which I can calculate the differences between, for example, the monthly values in 2019 and the monthly values in 2018, and perhaps create a new table or view that includes the 2018 dates in one column, 2019 dates in another and the difference in sensor reading value in a third ?

[image: example table]

Thanks

TP

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your data has no missing month/year, one option uses window functions:

```
select 
    t.*,
    lag(average) over(
        partition by sensor_id, extract(month from m)
        order by extract(year from m)
    ) last_year_average
from mytable
```

This puts all rows that belong to the same sensor and the same month in the same partition. You can then use the year part of the timestamp as an ordering column.

You can use the new column as needed to compare it to the current average.

Comment: Thanks for this .. combined with the options below you've both helped me out a lot

Answer (score 0):

If you have a value for every month, you can just use a 12-month lag:

```
select t.*,
       lag(average, 12) over (partition by sensor_id
                              order by m
                             ) as last_year_average
from t;
```

Filtering this to just 2019/2018 requires a subquery:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             lag(average, 12) over (partition by sensor_id
                                    order by m
                                   ) as last_year_average
      from t
     ) t
where m >= '2019-01-01'::date and
      m < '2020-01-01'::date
```

If you are missing months, then neither this (nor GMB's answer) will work correctly.  Instead, you can use a `join`, aggregation, or window function:

```
select t.*
from t left join
     t tprev
     on tprev.sensor_id = t.sensor_id and
        tprev.m = t.m - interval '12 month'
where t.m >= '2019-01-01'::date and t.m < '2020-01-01'::date;
```

Two other methods are:

```
select t.sensor_id, month(t.m)
       max(average) filter (where year(t.m) = 2019) as avg_2019,
       max(average) filter (where year(t.m) = 2018) as avg_2018
from t
group by t.sensor_id, month(t.m);
```

And to use window functions safely if there is the possibility of missing months:

```
select t.*,
       max(average) over (partition by sensor_id
                          order by m
                          range between '1 year preceding' and '1 year preceding'
                         ) as average_prev
from t;
```

Comment: Thanks for all of the options. I'm a beginner so plenty to work through. Your second option seems to do precisely what I am after, but I'm working through the others as well